# How to search for special characters in Github

Tags: github, special-characters

Is there any possibility to search github repos for strings containing a special characters (e.g. "example.com" or "Example: ").
As far as I know Github's search does not support it and Google ignores this as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. Just use sourcegraph or something else to search instead.

Answer (score 19):

The [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#considerations-for-code-search) says :

> You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query: . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ] @. The search will simply ignore these symbols.

Alternatively, you can [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) some repositories and [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) them.

Comment: Thanks for that! Anyway a possibility to search for these strings faster in online repos without cloning them would be great, but I'm afraid there's no search engine doing this.

Answer (score -2):

One way of doing this is to use a space instead of the character and put your search term in quotes. It will give you the closest results. 
I had a library call `sg.createNode` so I've searched for `"sg createNote"` which mostly returned results include `sg.createNote`

Comment: For the record this solution did help me accomplish what I needed to regardless of Github's search limitations. Maybe this would have been better suited as a comment to the original question instead of an answer?